# Get String from classes node cannot find symbol

Tags: java, class, nodes, symbols

I'm trying to get from Node of class String but the compiler cannot find the Variable. I would appreciate your help.

Student class:

```
public class Students {

    private int[] marks;
    private String name;

    public Students(String name, int[] marks) {
        this.name = name;
        marks = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
            this.marks[i] = marks[i];
        }
    }
    public int getMarksI(int i) {
        return marks[0];
    }
    public int[] getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The function where the problem:

```
public double AverageByName(Node < Students > s, String name) {
    Node < Students > p = s;
    while (p != null) {
        if (name == p.getName()) // this is the problem "cannot find symbol p.getName"
        {
            //
        }
        p.setNext();
    }
    return false;
}
```

In addition to that there is a class of Node and the linked list of the Students class created without a problem in the main.

Comment: despite your actual problem you should have a look at [how do i compare strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Look at the type of `p` - it's a `Node<Student>`, not `Student`. Now you haven't shown us the `Node` class, but presumably it's not got a `getName()` method...

Answer (score 1):

If Node exposes its Students value with `getValue()` it would be:

```
if (name.equals(p.getValue().getName()))
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate you help !

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
public double AverageByName(Node < Students > s, String name) {
Node < Students > p = s;
while (p != null) {
    if (name.equals(p.getValue().getName())) // you need to get the Student object from the node first
    {
        //
    }
    p.setNext();
}
return false;
```

}

or may be cast it to

```
Student std = (Student)p.getValue();
```

I have no idea from your question about the Node class. It would be better to share Node class also.